# How to make an absolutely positioned (overflow:hidden) container's absolutely positioned children show outside of their parent's area?

Tags: html, css, css-position

Please consider this example: ([working example](http://jsfiddle.net/yZdBD/3/))

Style declarations:

```
body {background:#333;font:1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
h1 {color:#ececec;text-align:center;margin:1.5em 0 1em;}
h2 {font-weight:normal;font-size:1.15em;
    padding-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #999;}
p {padding-right:1em;color:#000;}
pre {font-size:1em;color:#06f;margin:1em 0;}

#wrapper {position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;background:#ececec;
          overflow:hidden;zoom:1;padding:20px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;
          border-right:1px solid #000;border-top:1px solid #fff;
          border-left:1px solid #fff;}
.css {float:right;width:50%;}
.markup {float:left;width:50%;margin-right:-1px;}
.box1,
.box2,
.box3,
.box4 {background:#fff;position:absolute;padding:10px;border:1px solid #333;}
.box1 {left:0;top:-20px;}
.box2 {right:0;top:0;}
.box3 {left:0;bottom:0;}
.box4 {right:-20px;bottom:-20px;}
```

Markup:

```
<body>
<h1>overflow:hidden and absolutely positioned elements</h1>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="markup">

      <div class="box1">box 1</div>
        <div class="box2">box 2</div>
        <div class="box3">box 3</div>
        <div class="box4">box 4</div>
</div>
</body>
```

As you can see, `Box1` and `Box4` are clipped. How can I make them visible outside the containing divs' borders? Basically the boxes should be displayed like tooltips (they must be the topmost elements on the page).

Criteria regarding the preferred solution:

- no markup modifications
- no use of CSS3
- works cross browser
- the div with id `wrapper` must remain
  absolutely positioned and must remain `overflow:hidden`

**Edit:** I know that my requirements are tough, but I have to work with them. I have to solve this task in an enviroment I have no absolute control over.

**Edit #2:** Okay, here is WHY I need the boxes to not be relocated in the markup. In the concrete situation I want to use them as tooltips (specifically BeautyTips) for other elements. The position of the tooltip in the DOM tree is the result of the internal workings of the library. When I wanted to use BeautyTips, the problem that can be seen in my example prevented the display of the whole tooltip: it was clipped.

Comment: I'm no CSS expert but surely the whole point of `overflow:hidden` is that the child divs don't appear outside? Why do you need to have `overflow:hidden` if you don't want it's function?

Comment: You don't find your requirement illogical? It's like asking someone to run with 100 Km while the handbrake is up and you push the brake

Comment: Is a js modification of the css and/or dom structure acceptably within your critera?

Comment: With all the exact specifications you listed, without JS, **it is impossible**.

Comment: The wrapper div is not closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible with the conditions you have set. By definition, overflow:hidden clips any content or content within a descendant element that extends outside the viewport of the parent element.

The only way you are going to make it work is to either remove overflow:hidden or move the clipped boxes outside the wrapper.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html

Comment: By moving overflow:hidden to .markup and placing the boxes outside .markup but still inside wrapper the desired effect can be achieved. http://jsfiddle.net/yZdBD/16/

Comment: Edited my question to answer why I can't set neither the overflow property, nor move the boxes.

Comment: You're hosed then, you have to be able to make a change in order make it work.

Comment: I can't help but remark that "move the clipped boxes outside of the wrapper" breaks the principle of separating the document from the presentation, which is what HTML+CSS is supposed to provide.

Comment: Did you read the requirements of the original question @Kaz? It's the only way to display the contents of a div with overflow:hidden set. The correct answer is to change the markup, but that was explicitly prohibited in the requirements of the question.

Comment: @BrentFriar Yes, the correct answer is to change the markup, but that breaks the concept of separating markup from layout that CSS is supposed to provide because you're changing the document structure to achieve a layout effect, right? Thus CSS is broken. We should be able to achieve any layout with any document structure we want. Why should objects be clipped in a certain way on the rendered page just because the document's syntax tree is nested in a particular way.

Comment: What you are suggesting is impossible. The entire point of setting the overflow property to hidden is to stop the display of anything that falls outside the boundaries of the parent container with that property. CSS is not broken, the requirements set for the original question are.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your box `#wrapper` is the first non-default positioned ancestor and so forms the bounding box for `box1` to `box4`. And since you've set `#wrapper` to `overflow: hidden` it is hiding the parts of `box1` to `box4` that overlap its edge.

You could remove `overflow: hidden` from `#wrapper`, or you could move these boxes outside `#wrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow:hidden` from `wrapper` and its done.